# Navigation mesh not found in properties

Tags: mesh

I have been following a Blender book which asks me to build a navigation mesh (Properties > Scene > Build navigation mesh) but I am unable to find it in my installation. The version the author of the book is using is 2.6.3 and I am using 2.74 that is probably why. Is there any alternative to building a navigation mesh, or has the option been shifted elsewhere?

Comment: Hi Saurabh, I'm sorry but I don't know what is a "navigation mesh". What is the purpose of the chapter you're reading in the book? Which book is it? Please elaborate a bit your question (click the edit button above) so we can figure out what exactly is the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must enable the blender game engine, there you will find the navigation mesh